# Choose between bit field integer versus struct?

Tags: c, performance, struct, enums

Let's say that there's a need to keep a set of a few flags together (in a C-based language), there are two options to do this: using a `struct` of bit fields or using initialized enumeration. Which one is more efficient in terms of run-time performance and what are the caveats that the option implies?

Option A:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int onion : 1; 
    unsigned int pickle : 1;
    unsigned int jalapeno : 1;
    unsigned int cucumber : 1;
} __attribute__((packed)) SandwichVegetable;
```

Usage example of Option A, suppose that you want to have just onion and pickle and we have zero-initialized structs by default:

```
SandwichVegetable mine;
mine.onion = 1;
mine.pickle = 1;
```

Option B:

```
typedef enum {
    SandwichVegetableOnion = 1,
    SandwichVegetablePickle = 1 << 2,
    SandwichVegetableJalapeno = 1 << 3,
    SandwichVegetableCucumber = 1 << 4
} SandwichVegetable;
```

As an example of Option B, again if we want to have just onion and pickle and again we have everything zero-initialized by the compiler:

```
SandwichVegetable mine;
mine = SandwichVegetableOnion | SandwichVegetablePickle;
```

Comment: Option 2 i like, but it's my opinion. This is opinion based unless someone can expose a good reason, I choose option 2 because it makes it clear what you are doing.

Comment: You can look for random collections of values more easily with the enum.  Deciding at runtime to look for jalapeno, cucumber and pickle is (probably) easier than accessing the bit fields separately.  Bit fields are incredibly implementation defined, and are apt to lead to larger code than you'd expect/hope for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitfields are a strange and infrequently used language feature, so many compilers have trouble with them. ([Here's one example](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=48696); [here's another](http://lwn.net/Articles/478657/).) If you have any choice in the matter, you're probably best off using boolean masks.

Answer (score 1):

Both are equivalent in runtime. The former however requires compiler-specific attributes and is harder to create values.